# Game Center multiplayer matchmaking issue

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-x, game-center

I am trying to create a real time multiplayer game using Game Center. For matchmaking, I am using programmatic approach by using the following code:

```
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
            // Process the error.
            NSLog(@" error => %@ ", [error userInfo] );

        }
        else if (match != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Match Found _-----------");
            currentMatch = match;
            match.delegate = self;

            NSLog(@"Expected player count:%ld",match.expectedPlayerCount);

            if ( match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"Ready to start match!");

            }
        }
    }];
```

Currently, the code generates following error when a match is found:

```
ABC-mobile[342:26698] [log]  [ERROR] ReXmitCollectionRequest:640 /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AVConference/AVConference-1020.31/ICE.subproj/Sources/ICEMessage.c:640:     ReXmit [SNATMAP_REQUEST] (1:0) from [192.168.0.104:16402] to [17.133.234.32:16384] failed (801A0002)

ABC-mobile[342:26698] [log]  [ERROR] -[GKConnectionInternal internal_setRemoteConnectionData:fromParticipantID:pendingConnectionPIDList:]:1041 GCKSessionPrepareConnection FAILED(80150016)
```

I am using **Cocos2D-X** game engine and I am calling this method from a **C++** function.

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Use pure **Objective-C** code (file should have **.m** extension instead of **.mm**). Write a wrapper class in **Objective-C++** (file with **.mm** extension) to call these Game Center methods.

Comment: There's no need to use Objective-C exclusively (.m) for this. It will work as Objective-C++ as well, you just need to make sure the wrapper methods are defined in a C++ header. You haven't provided any of the code you used to do so, so who knows why it didn't work that way for you.

You could also make bare calls to `objc_msgSend` if this is really the only thing you are using GK for.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this problem and there was very little information anywhere on the web about it.

```
2023-10-31 17:44:22.256821+0900 Real-Time Game Sample[663:76416] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] ReXmitCollectionRequest:629 /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AVConference/ICE.subproj/Sources/ICEMessage.c:629:   ReXmit [SNATMAP_REQUEST] (1:0) from [183.102.108.243:16402] to [17.188.182.97:3480] failed (801A0002)
2023-10-31 17:44:22.258946+0900 Real-Time Game Sample[663:76416] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] ReXmitCollectionRequest:629 /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AVConference/ICE.subproj/Sources/ICEMessage.c:629:   ReXmit [SNATMAP_REQUEST] (1:0) from [183.102.108.243:16402] to [17.188.182.97:3480] failed (801A0002)
... HUNDREDS MORE...
2023-10-31 17:44:26.736101+0900 Real-Time Game Sample[663:76416] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] ReXmitCollectionRequest:629 /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AVConference/ICE.subproj/Sources/ICEMessage.c:629:   ReXmit [SNATMAP_REQUEST] (1:0) from [183.102.108.243:16402] to [17.188.182.97:3480] failed (801A0002)
2023-10-31 17:44:26.737198+0900 Real-Time Game Sample[663:76416] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] ReXmitCollectionRequest:629 /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AVConference/ICE.subproj/Sources/ICEMessage.c:629:   ReXmit [SNATMAP_REQUEST] (1:0) from [183.102.108.243:16402] to [17.188.182.97:3480] failed (801A0002)
2023-10-31 17:44:26.738326+0900 Real-Time Game Sample[663:76416] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] -[GKConnectionInternal internal_setRemoteConnectionData:fromParticipantID:pendingConnectionPIDList:]:1047 GCKSessionPrepareConnection FAILED(80150016)
```

Viceroy is apparently the peer to peer connectivity framework that `GameKit` uses for its real time connectivity. This is an internal error that doesn't provide any information why there is a failure.

This happens to me when my `GKMatch` object that is generated after a `findMatch` request is fulfilled does not have a `delegate`. It is trying to push the information to the delegate, but failing, causing the session to not connect.

For example, if you have

```swift
    public func findPlayer() async {
        let request = GKMatchRequest()
        request.minPlayers = 2
        request.maxPlayers = 2
        let match: GKMatch
        
        do {
            match = try await GKMatchmaker.shared().findMatch(for: request)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription).")
            return
        }
        
        start(match: match)

        GKMatchmaker.shared().finishMatchmaking(for: match)
    }
```

And then the `start(match:)` function looks like this

```swift
    public func start(match: GKMatch) {
        guard match.expectedPlayerCount == 0
        else {
            return
        }
        
        currentMatch = match
        currentMatch?.delegate = self
    }
```

Notice the delegate isn't set based on if the `expectedPlayerCount` is 0. This caused the failure and setting the delegate immediately after the match is found solves the problem.

So the final working solution was the following:

```swift
    public func findPlayer() async {
        let request = GKMatchRequest()
        request.minPlayers = 2
        request.maxPlayers = 2
        let match: GKMatch
        
        do {
            match = try await GKMatchmaker.shared().findMatch(for: request)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription).")
            return
        }
        
        currentMatch = match
        currentMatch?.delegate = self
        
        start(match: match)

        GKMatchmaker.shared().finishMatchmaking(for: match)
    }

    public func start(match: GKMatch) {
        guard match.expectedPlayerCount == 0
        else {
            return
        }
        
        // Start Game Logic
    }

    // MARK: - GKMatch Delegate
    public func match(
        _ match: GKMatch,
        player: GKPlayer,
        didChange state: GKPlayerConnectionState
    ) {
        switch state {
        case .connected:
            print("\(player.displayName) Connected")
        case .disconnected:
            print("\(player.displayName) Disconnected")
        default:
            print("\(player.displayName) Connection Unknown")
        }
        
        start(match: match)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I will never suggest doing match-making deploying your code on your own cloud-infra. I did it using AWS lambda + dynamodb combination. Dynamo db facilitated atomic operations on table keys. Those keys could be your skill set points of players for match-making. Firebase cloud function + RealtimeDB (Try CloudStore too. That's Firebase new product) is another option to develop matchmaking framework. It doesn't provide atomicity on key but there is another concept of PushKey. That works too.

Both of these are the major cloud vendors, so you won't have to worry about latency or downtime. I set up my center in the US on Firebase RealtimeDB and from India, I was able to transfer event to another player in India within 500ms.

Both of these have a certain limit of connections/requests free (I guess Firebase has more number of connections free than AWS. You might need to check). So, you won't incur any cost for a long time till your game actually starts making money. On my AWS Lambda + DynamoDB combination, I was able to do 11k match-making every day without paying a penny.

And above all, both of these provide regional centers too. So when you scale up, you can create multi-region centers.

But both of these vendors probably don't work on C++ or Objective-C++. I developed my models on Javascript and JAVA. Maybe a few other languages are supported too. You might want to check.